# Iterating through all divs in a class and getting text from a specific elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the text of each div with class `.list` in class `.lists` and get the text from the `.lineone` class. In the example below it's `"Reilly  Lawless"`

```
<div class="lists">
   <div class="list history0" id="history0">
      <div class="info">
         <a href="/user/reillylawless23"><a href="/user/reillylawless23">
         <a href="/user/reillylawless23">
            <div class="picture monophoto">
               <div class="text" style="font-size: 34px; margin-top: 4.125px;">RJL</div>
               <div class="img" style="background-image: url();"></div>
            </div>
         </a>
         </a></a>
         <div class="right">
            <a class="removelinkdefault" href="/user/reillylawless23"><a class="removelinkdefault" href="/user/reillylawless23">
            <a class="removelinkdefault" href="/user/reillylawless23">
               <div class="lineone">Reilly  Lawless</div>
            </a>
            </a></a>
            <div class="linetwo">reillylawless23's List</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <a href="/user/reillylawless23"><a href="/user/reillylawless23">
      <a href="/user/reillylawless23">
         <div class="boxes">
            <div class="left">
               <div class="box box1" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://s3.amazonaws.com/22hints/hints/55b10e3610cd68.77289350.jpg&quot;);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
               <div class="box box2" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://s3.amazonaws.com/22hints/hints/55ca535e973368.44212514.jpg&quot;);"></div>
               <div class="box box3" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://secondglobe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Miraculous-Lake-Carrera-in-Buenos-Aires-3.jpg&quot;);"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </a>
      </a></a>
      <a class="cbutton whiteonblack" href="/user/reillylawless23">
         VIEW LIST<!--SEE <span class="owner">JOHN'S</span>-->
      </a>
   </div>
<!-- then <div class="list history1" id="history1"> and so on -->
</div>
```

Here is my attempts at getting it via jQuery:

```
 $(".lists .list").each(function(index) {
      //this returns all of the text for all of .lineone each time
      var hint_name = $('.lineone').text();
      //this returns nothing
      var hint_name = $(this).children('.lineone').text();                
 });
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Here `$('.lineone')` you grab all elements with that class on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is missing the `.lineone`. From there you can use the `this` keyword in the `each` handler function to refer to the current element in the iteration. Try this:

```
$(".lists .list .lineone").each(function(index) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    // do something with the text here...
});
```

If you're iterating through each `.list` intentionally and want to find the `.lineone` within that you need to use `find()` as `children()` only searches for direct descendants:

```
$(".lists .list").each(function(index) {
    var text = $(this).find('.lineone').text();
    // do something with the text here...               
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`.lineone` is not a *direct* child of `.list` - it's a descendent

```
var hint_name = $(this).children('.lineone').text();
```

could be

```
var hint_name = $(this).find('.lineone').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `context` within selector set to `this` : current `.list` element within `.each()` iteration

```js
$(".lists .list").each(function(index) {
      //this returns all of the text for all of .lineone each time
      var hint_name = $(".lineone", this).text();
      //this returns nothing
      // var hint_name = $(this).children('.lineone').text();  
   console.log(hint_name)
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="lists">
   <div class="list history0" id="history0">
      <div class="info">
         <a href="/user/reillylawless23"><a href="/user/reillylawless23">
         <a href="/user/reillylawless23">
            <div class="picture monophoto">
               <div class="text" style="font-size: 34px; margin-top: 4.125px;">RJL</div>
               <div class="img" style="background-image: url();"></div>
            </div>
         </a>
         </a></a>
         <div class="right">
            <a class="removelinkdefault" href="/user/reillylawless23"><a class="removelinkdefault" href="/user/reillylawless23">
            <a class="removelinkdefault" href="/user/reillylawless23">
               <div class="lineone">Reilly  Lawless</div>
            </a>
            </a></a>
            <div class="linetwo">reillylawless23's List</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <a href="/user/reillylawless23"><a href="/user/reillylawless23">
      <a href="/user/reillylawless23">
         <div class="boxes">
            <div class="left">
               <div class="box box1" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://s3.amazonaws.com/22hints/hints/55b10e3610cd68.77289350.jpg&quot;);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
               <div class="box box2" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://s3.amazonaws.com/22hints/hints/55ca535e973368.44212514.jpg&quot;);"></div>
               <div class="box box3" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://secondglobe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Miraculous-Lake-Carrera-in-Buenos-Aires-3.jpg&quot;);"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </a>
      </a></a>
      <a class="cbutton whiteonblack" href="/user/reillylawless23">
         VIEW LIST<!--SEE <span class="owner">JOHN'S</span>-->
      </a>
   </div>
<!-- then <div class="list history1" id="history1"> and so on -->
</div>
```